# How to request focus on the error message (for accessibility reasons)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

I have a field where a user is supposed to fill in a password and in the case when the password is incorrect there is a text field appears under the password field where it says "Password incorrect".

I need to adjust accessibility (for blind people) that will read the text field loud out  where it is written - "Password incorrect". In order to do so (as far as I understand) I need to request focus on this error text once it is error state.

There is my code:

```
...
    @Composable
    private fun OTPBlock(
        isErrorState: StateFlow<Boolean>
    ) {
        val isError: Boolean by isErrorState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

...

        if (isError) {
            ErrorOtpViewMsg(isErrorState = isErrorState)
        }

...
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ErrorOtpViewMsg(isErrorState: StateFlow<Boolean>) {
        val isError: Boolean by isErrorState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
        val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

        LaunchedEffect(isError) {
            if (isError) {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        }

        BounceAnimatedVisibility(isVisible = isError) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_exclamation),
                    contentDescription = null
                )

                Text(
                    text = stringResource(...),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = ...
                )
            }
        }
    }
...
```

The idea is that once this function `ErrorOtpViewMsg` will be invoked `LaunchedEffect` fires `focusRequester.requestFocus`, and focus moves to the `Row` with a text that is supposed to be read out loud (in accessibility mode).

I tried to debug it and I see that everything goes through the flow as expected, but it doesn't read the text out loud.

What am I missing here?

**UPD**

Following the answer by @Jan Itor I tried his suggestion and it didn't work, so I decided to try exactly the same code but in the new project with just a clean activity, where it is a button and error field, so once a user clicks on the button, error field appears and focus moves there and I was surprised that everything was working as expected.

I know it shouldn't be possible that exactly the same code works differently, thus there are some differences that I am not able to catch.

The question is - is there a way to kind of debug or test focus functionality? I mean I see that the flow goes as expected, but for some reasons it doesn't work specifically in my project

Any suggestions are appreciated :)

**UPD2**

There is my updated code, I simplified it

1. I removed animation
2. Added logs
3. Added focus event

in order to find out what is going on:

```
...
    @Composable
    private fun OTPBlock(
        isVerifyBtnEnabledState: MutableStateFlow<Boolean>,
        isErrorState: StateFlow<Boolean>,
        onOtpTextChange: (code: String, isOtpInputFilled: Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        val error: MutableState<Boolean> = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        OTPCodeWidget(
            isErrorState = isErrorState,
            onOtpTextChange = onOtpTextChange
        )

        if (error.value) {
            ErrorOtpViewMsg()
        }

        VerifyBtn(
            isEnabledState = isVerifyBtnEnabledState,
            onVerifyBtnClicked = {
                Log.e("HERE", "1 VerifyBtn clicked: ${error.value}")
                error.value = !error.value
                Log.e("HERE", "2 VerifyBtn clicked: ${error.value}")
            }
        )
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ErrorOtpViewMsg() {
        Log.e("HERE", ">>> START COMPOSITION")
        val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            Log.e("HERE", ">>> FOCUS REQUEST START")

            this.coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion {
                Log.e("HERE", "1 <<< FOCUS REQUEST END")
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
                Log.e("HERE", "2 <<< FOCUS REQUEST END")
            }
        }

        Log.e("HERE", "3 OTPBlock")
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = ...),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_exclamation),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = ...,
            )


            Log.e("HERE", "4 OTPBlock")

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .semantics {
                        contentDescription = "Error description"
                        onClick(label = "toggle newsletter subscription", action = null)
                    }
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .clickable { Log.e("HERE", "ErrorOtpViewMsg: ") }
                    .onFocusChanged { Log.e("HERE", "Focus: ${it.hasFocus}") }
                    .focusable(),
                text = stringResource(...),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                color = ...,
                style = ...
            )
        }

        Log.e("HERE", "<<< END COMPOSITION")
    }
```

There is a log I get:

```
13:47:21.680  E  1 VerifyBtn clicked: false
13:47:21.681  E  2 VerifyBtn clicked: true
13:47:21.694  E  >>> START COMPOSITION
13:47:21.695  E  3 OTPBlock
13:47:21.725  E  4 OTPBlock
13:47:21.728  E  <<< END COMPOSITION
13:47:21.740  E  Focus: false
13:47:21.762  E  >>> FOCUS REQUEST START
13:47:21.762  E  1 <<< FOCUS REQUEST END
13:47:21.766  E  Focus: true
13:47:21.766  E  2 <<< FOCUS REQUEST END
```

So here I can see that there is only one time composition, also focus requests after the composition is done and finally I see that focus state changed to `true`, but still it doesn't read out loud the text.

P.S. When I click on the text manually it reads out loud as expected (but not with focus request).

Comment: You shouldn't be requesting focus, that can disorient users. You could make the error a live region so that it is announced ```Modifier.semantics { liveRegion = LiveRegionMode.Assertive }```

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon yep, it helps finally, would you like to post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, thank you - I've become reluctant to post answers as sometimes people will get technical ("This question is *actually* about requesting focus") rather than trying to actually solve the problem. So let's see how this goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer posted at the request of the asker:

If the goal is to make the app accessible, requesting focus is not the optimal solution. So while the question may be about requesting focus, the ideal solution does not in fact do this. The defence is detailed below my recommended answer.

You could make the error a live region so that it is announced:

```
Modifier...
.semantics { 
    ...
    liveRegion = LiveRegionMode.Assertive 
}
```

The purpose of a LiveRegion, as from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/semantics/LiveRegionMode):

> Live region indicates to accessibility services they should automatically notify the user about changes to the node's content description or text, or to the content descriptions or text of the node's children (where applicable).

Put simply, a view that is a LiveRegion will make an announcement when some part of it's value is modified or updated. This should work better for assistive technology users as you are not changing their point of focus while using your application, which can lead to disorientation.

To add to the reasoning, if you request focus, you could be failing a basic [Web Content Accessibility Criteria: 1.4.13 Content on Hover or Focus (Level AA)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#content-on-hover-or-focus):

> Where receiving and then removing pointer hover or keyboard focus triggers additional content to become visible and then hidden, the following are true:
>
> - Dismissible: A mechanism is available to dismiss the additional content without moving pointer hover or keyboard focus, unless the additional content communicates an input error or does not obscure or replace other content;
>   ...

Dismissible in this case would mean that the user can press back and receive their original focus, which sounds like an awful lot of work and maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `focusable` modifier which should go after the `focusRequester` as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/FocusRequester).

Also, `Row` doesn't know what to do with the focus. You could either move focus modifiers to the `Text` you want to be read or add [semantics](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/semantics#properties) to the `Row`. For example:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .semantics { contentDescription = "Error description" }
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .focusable()
//...
```

Edit:

Focus request might fail if your composable is not visible due to animation.
To fix it you could:

- Add a `delay` before `focusRequester.requestFocus()`. No guarantees that this will work every time.
- Wait for animation to end. I don't know what `BounceAnimatedVisibility` is, but standard `AnimatedVisibility` provides `AnimatedVisibilityScope` which has `transition` property that can be checked for animation end. Try this approach:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun OTPBlock(
    isErrorState: StateFlow<Boolean>
) {
    val isError: Boolean by isErrorState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    AnimatedVisibility(visible = isError) {
        ErrorOtpViewMsg(transition.currentState == transition.targetState)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ErrorOtpViewMsg(canFocus: Boolean) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    LaunchedEffect(canFocus) {
        if (canFocus) {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
    val message by remember { mutableStateOf("Error text") }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .semantics { contentDescription = message }
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .focusable(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_exclamation),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(
            text = message,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, your suggestions make sense, I tried it, however, there are still some weird issues, I posted a UPD in my initial question. Could you please take a look maybe you would have any suggestions there?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `BounceAnimatedVisibility`? To debug focus status you could add something like `.onFocusChanged { println("Focus: ${it.hasFocus}") }` before `.focusable`. @Sirop4ik

Comment: Yep, I tried all of your suggestions, and updated my question, could you please take a look ?

Comment: Try adding a small `delay(50)` before request. @Sirop4ik